# How to send url with parameters from windows phone 8

Tags: c#, php, xml, windows-phone-8

I want to get 2 parametrs from windows phone 8 to php index file , with get or post method
any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{

};
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://example.com?par1={0}&par2={1}", "param1", "param2"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: @Kub6opr It sends parameters but i cant catch parameters in php file

Comment: If problem in PHP why you ask about windows phone?

Comment: no. problem was windows phone 8 emulator